# Why does C# let me compile sort code when it doesnt know how to sort

Tags: c#, sorting

I thought it was odd that C# let me call sort on my class and not specify a way to sort them nor write a compare overload. When i ran this code this error popped up

```
List<MyClass> myClassArray= new List<MyClass>();
//myClassArray.add(...);
myClassArray.Sort();

An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Failed to compare two elements in the array.
```

Why does C# let me compile this code when it doesnt know how to sort this!
-edit-

Codex ask why it does this. I wrote a theory on why it does it in my comments. Here some example code.

```
class A : IComparable<A>
{
    public int CompareTo(A a) { return 0; }
}
class C //: IComparable<A>
{
    public int CompareTo(A a) { return 0; }
}
    static void test()
    {
        A a = new A();
        bool b;
        C c = new C();

        object o = a;
        IComparable<A> ia = (IComparable<A>)o;
        b = ia == ia;

        o = c;
        IComparable<A> ic = (IComparable<A>)o;
        b = ic == ic;

        //uncomment this to get a compile time error
        //IComparable<A> ic2 = c;
        return;
    }
```

If you uncomment the line before return, you'll get a compile time error. When you uncomment IComparable in class c, it will compile and work.

Comment: BTW solution to sort is adding : IComparable<T> to your class definition and defining the int CompareTo(T) function.

Comment: @acidzombie24 : I agree with the question "I dont understand how it compiles?" I haven't found a convincing answer. Could you please share yours?

Comment: Codex: Judgingt by jeffamaphone and Marc Gravell answer the only only conclusion i came up was C# keeps track of the type of all vars during runtime (this is why object works?) along with method name and signature. Because of the availability of types at runtime i assume they try typecasting it to

Comment: a type/base that is supported (IComparable or IComparable<T>). Then since it cant do it it throws an exception that it couldnt figure out a way to compare them.

Comment: i wrote out example code and pasted it above. I think i may be wrong about method signatures (otherewise it could do duck typing. Marc Gravell mention duck typing and it does seem to do it in a way).  I think it keep track of interfaces inherited.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no constraint on the generic parameter of List<T> requiring it to implement IComparable<T>.  If there were, it would (sort of) guarantee that elements could be sorted, but you wouldn't be able to use List<T> to hold anything that didn't implement IComparable.  And since you probably won't be sorting every list you create, this is the right decision.

Comment: Why does myClassArray have a sort method? why doesnt it force me to do sort(myList, myCompare); or something. I dont understand how it compiles. Is this a virtual method that throws if its empty? does this have something to do with dynamic types? your answer is great but i want more info.

Answer (score 2):

Sort should be checking to see if your object implements [IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx).  This is a run time check, and since you presumably don't implement it the default comparer doesn't know what to do with your objects, so it throws the exception.

It lets it compile because this isn't a language feature, its a framework feature.

Answer (score 2):

Just for additional info; essentially, it uses `Comparer<T>.Default` to do the comparisons. This implements `IComparer<T>`, and can compare 2 objects of type `T`. The actual implementation is selected the first time you ask for it (per `T`); there are a number of patterns that the framework uses to pick the implementation - for example, classes, "regular" structs, and `Nullable<T>` are all handled separately. Likewise, it makes choices based on whether `T` implements `IComparable<T>`, `IComparable`, or neither (in which case it throws an exception).

This provides a very easy way to do "duck type" sorting. Likewise, there is also an `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` that checks for `IEquatable<T>`, defaulting to `object.Equals` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

C# arguably could have just have some baked in notion in System.Object about how you order objects like it did with `Equals` to compare them for identity.

Unfortunately, this leads to concerns about intensionality vs. extensionality, localizationm etc.

There is an `IComparable<T>` interface, but the built-in value types can't implement interfaces like that.

Therefore, there is no good way to just look at a type at compile time and know definitively if it has a meaningful ordering. =(

The mechanism that has evolved in C# is to use the `IComparer<T>` instance that is returned by `Comparer<T>.Default` and get a runtime error when you try to sort something which lacks an ordering.

By allowing multiple `IComparer`s and `IComparer<T>`s, you can have a notion of multiple alternative orderings that work on the same type, so that much is good, but all is not well.

Internally, c# uses a bunch of rules to find `Comparer<T>.Default`, which it handles differently if T is an instance of  `IComparable<T>` or is of the form `Nullable<T>`, etc.

e.g. the code from [system/collections/generic/comparer.cs](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid9F67062D1E3BF9542BF6C232AFC481E49AC6D728.aspx?s=Comparer%3CT%3E+System.Collections.Generic#L27):

```
    public static Comparer<T> Default {
        get {
            Comparer<T> comparer = defaultComparer;
            if (comparer == null) {
                comparer = CreateComparer();
                defaultComparer = comparer;
            }
            return comparer;
        }
    }

    private static Comparer<T> CreateComparer() {
        Type t = typeof(T);
        // If T implements IComparable<T> return a GenericComparer<T>
        if (typeof(IComparable<T>).IsAssignableFrom(t)) {
            //return (Comparer<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(GenericComparer<>).MakeGenericType(t));
            return (Comparer<T>)(typeof(GenericComparer<int>).TypeHandle.CreateInstanceForAnotherGenericParameter(t));
        }
        // If T is a Nullable<U> where U implements IComparable<U> return a NullableComparer<U>
        if (t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>)) {
            Type u = t.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            if (typeof(IComparable<>).MakeGenericType(u).IsAssignableFrom(u)) {
                //return (Comparer<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(NullableComparer<>).MakeGenericType(u));
                return (Comparer<T>)(typeof(NullableComparer<int>).TypeHandle.CreateInstanceForAnotherGenericParameter(u));                
            }
        }
        // Otherwise return an ObjectComparer<T>
        return new ObjectComparer<T>();
    }
```

In essence, this lets Microsoft gradually add special cases for their own code, but unfortunately the code that results from just using `Comparer<T>.Default` for a custom `IComparable<T>` instance is pretty abysmal.

The Sort method on `IList<T>`, presumes that `Comparer<T>.Default` will come up with something it can use to compare your objects, but it has no way to look at the type T and tell that it does, so it assumes it is safe and only realizes later at runtime that `MyClass` isn't playing along.